# How order magento 2 EE customer custom attributes?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, customer-attribute, magento-enterprise-2

I'm using **magento 2.1.7 EE** and customer custom attributes creation in built, so I have added three attributes **customer_title, customer_type and industry_type**

So I want to display all three categories separately in my desired places. Still didn't find a way to show it.

Following section shows the all customer custom attributes together.

```
<?php $customerAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_user_attributes'); ?>
<?php if ($customerAttributes): ?>
<?php $customerAttributes->setEntityType('customer')->setShowContainer(false);?>
<?php $block->restoreSessionData($customerAttributes->getMetadataForm());?>
<?php echo $customerAttributes->toHtml()?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Need help.

Comment: @akgola do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm waiting 5 days for an answer, finally I found a shortcut.
So I think better to post it here.

This will helpful to developer who needs to customize the register post.

Register page show Customer attribute as follows,

```
$customerAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_user_attributes');

if ($customerAttributes): 
  $customerAttributes->setEntityType('customer')->setShowContainer(false);
  $block->restoreSessionData($customerAttributes->getMetadataForm());
  echo $customerAttributes->toHtml(); // Here display the all customer attributes
endif;
```

So I found the getUserDefinedAttributes() method checking the module block,

then modified the code as,

```
if ($customerAttributes): 
  // Read the all customer attributes.
  foreach ($customerAttributes->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):
    // Check the attribute code and I want to show customer_title so filter it using if.
    if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == "customer_title"):
      // get attribute content using filtered $attribute
      $attributeContent = $customerAttributes->getAttributeHtml($attribute);
      if ($attributeContent):
        echo $attributeContent; // Display customer_title attribute content
      endif;
     endif;
   endforeach;
endif;
```

This helps for customer address attributes also.